# What should be passed to super() when extending a class in Python?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I've noticed that a lot of people pass the child class to the call to the parent constructed:

```
class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(ChildClass, self).__init__()
```

But sometimes I see this:

```
class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__()
```

Where nothing is passed to the parent constructor.

So far, every time I see the first method in some code I want to use, I've been able to replace it with the second method with no problems. I'm wondering if I can just use the second way universally?

Comment: The second way is the Python 3 way. As long as you're using Python 3 (which you should be), you can use the second way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The super() function is used to give access to methods and properties of a parent or sibling class.
The super() function returns an object that represents the parent class.
If you have python v3, its okay to not pass any arguements to the super function. However, if you python v2, you need to arguements.

Syntax for python 3 -

```
super().methoName(args)
```

Syntax for older versions-

```
super(subClass, instance).method(args)
```